# Android Pay - How does Merchant provide data to 3rd party app?

Tags: android, google-api, payment, payment-processing, android-pay

I'm interested in integrating Android Pay into my Android app. I had a question about how the Merchant provides data to the app.

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/get-started

Lets say, if I am "Nike" and I want to sell a product in App XXX. What data is required to be provided to App XXX to sell a product (ex: Men's shoes)?

I'm assuming the Merchant will of course need to provide Product information (name, details, price).

1. However, how does the merchant get the payment/shipping information from the customer?
2. Does the merchant provide an e-mail to the Android Pay interface?
3. Does the merchant need to provide a unique Android Pay Merchant ID #?
4. How does the merchant get the Virtual Account Number?
5. I'm not too familiar with the term "payment processor" from the guide. What is a merchant's payment processor and how is it communicated to the Android Pay interface?